# Bulk Renaming Files isnt working for me

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am running a shell script on my mac, and i am getting a "No Such file or directory.

The input is:  the replacement_name, and the working dir.
The output is: changing all files in the directory from `$file` to `$newfilename`

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "-------------------------------------------------"
echo "Arguments:"
echo "Old File String: $1"
echo "New File Name Head: $2"
echo "Directory to Change: $3"
echo "-------------------------------------------------"
oldname="$1"
newname="$2"
abspath="$3"
echo "Updating all files in '$abspath' to $newname.{extension}"

for file in $(ls $abspath);
do
    echo $file
    echo $file | sed -e "s/$oldname/$newname/g"
    newfilename=$("echo $file| sed -e \"s/$oldname/$newname/g\"")
    echo "NEW FILE: $newfilename"
    mv $abspath/$file $abspath/$newfilename
done
```

It seems that it doesnt like assigning the result of my 1-liner to a variable.

```
old_filename_string_template.dart
test_template.dart
./bulk_rename.sh: line 16: echo old_filename_string.dart| sed -e "s/old_filename_string/test/g": No such file or directory
NEW FILE:
```

Test Information:

```
 mkdir /_temp_folder
 touch old_filename_string_template.a  old_filename_string_template.b  old_filename_string_template.c old_filename_string1_template.a  old_filename_string1_template.b  old_filename_string1_template.c old_filename_string3_template.a  old_filename_string3_template.b  old_filename_string3_template.c
./convert.sh old_filename_string helloworld /_temp_folder
```

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Quote expansions, remove the double quotes inside `$(...)` and use [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/).

Comment: Also, you could add some input and expected output. You might get better solutions to your problem that way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The double quotes here make the shell look for a command whose name (filename, alias, or function name) is the entire string between the quotes. Obviously, no such command exists.

```
> newfilename=$("echo $file| sed -e \"s/old_filename_string/$1/g\"")
```

Removing the double quotes inside the parentheses and the backslashes before the remaining ones will fix this particular error.

The construct `$(command sequence)` is called a *command substitution;* the shell effectively replaces this string with the standard output obtained by evaluating `command sequence` in a subshell.

Most of the rest of your script has **much** too few quotes; so it's really unclear why you added them here in particular. http://shellcheck.net/ is a useful service which will point out a few dozen  more trivial errors. Briefly, anything which contains a file name should be between double quotes.

Comment: i started with something like:   `newfilename=echo $file | sed...` but that was not working.  Thats why you see it returning correctly on the line above, but for variable assignment it seems to be causing me the issues.  It seems that the proper answer would be: `newfilename="$(echo file | sed -e s/old_file_string/$1/g)"` and it seems to work properly

Answer (score 0):

Try to put double quotes outside backticks/subtitutions (not INSIDE backticks/substitutions like `$("...")`)

```
newfilename="$(....)"
```

---

By the way, please consider to use the package [perl rename](http://search.cpan.org/~pederst/rename/) which already does this bulk file rename very well, with `Perl` regex style which is easier to use. This `perl rename` command maybe alreay available in your (Mac) distro. See [intro pages](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/rename.htm).

Comment: perl rename is not a default package on my machine.  I will not be downloading a package to solve the problem, because then I need to add an installer to the script

Comment: @Fallenreaper: ok, I am using linux, and this is a quite popular command, just works for decades. I do not know Mac.

Comment: In `newfilename="$(....)"`, the quotes are actually not needed, see [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters) about the expansions taking place when assigning. Doesn't hurt either, though.